# CSV Data Config not working correctly with my Thread-Loop

Tags: jmeter

I'm new in Jmeter and have a problem with loading user data from csv file within a thread loop.

I created a little testsuite.

- threadgroup (Number of threads: 1, loop count 2)

  - load user data with csv data config
    csv looks like this:
    user1; password
    user2; password
    ....
  - simple http request

If I run my test I will get this output:
- http request for user1
- http request for user2

I would have expected that only for user1 the request would be executed twice.
What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the described behavior you need to:

1. Amend your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to have 2 threads and 1 loop

   [image]
2. Amend [**Sharing Mode**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) of your CSV Data Set Config to be `Current Thread` or [`${__threadNum}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what do I have to do if I want to execute a request for several users? With this example I can only execute requests for the first user in my CSV file. But my csv file has several users

I will do the following test:

for every user in my csv file do a http request (as often as specified by loop count in my thread group)

Example:

CSV has 10 users
Loop Count 5
Do for every of the 10 users the http request 5 times